# django psycopg2 and postgresql insertion error

Tags: django, psycopg2, postgresql-9.1

I'm having trouble adding any data to my database. It lets me modify entries in tables, but any action that will create a new row or new column in a database is mysteriously failing. Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.4-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 107, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.4-py2.7.egg/south/migration/__init__.py", line 219, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.4-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 235, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.4-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 310, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.4-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 134, in migrate
    self.done_migrate(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.4-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 113, in done_migrate
    self.record(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.4-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 280, in record
    record.save()
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 463, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 551, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 203, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1576, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 910, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: syntax error at or near "RETURNING" at character 171
```

It was working fine until I migrated databases to another server. Now I'm having all sorts of trouble and I'm unsure what to do. Also, this seems to happen for South as well if trying to add a field to the database. Curiously, modifying existing objects / columns in the database succeeds without failure. I'm really unsure what to do and would love any assistance.

Comment: What is the version of postgresql you are using? Can you confirm its 9.1?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.1.23, Django requires 9.1 right? or at least with the psycopg2 backend (i assume psycopg is for < 9.1). Thanks for the insight that's exactly the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8.1 doesn't support the `RETURNING` clause. So upgrade your database version to the current stable release.

Answer (score 0):

8.1 doesn't support RETURNING ids of inserted objects so you need to disable it.

```
from django.db import connection
##just before insert statement
connection.features.can_return_id_from_insert = False    
###some insert statement
```